# merge two rows in one row and convert to NA

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

```
   Dataframe:
     0     1    2   3     4      slicing
0   NaN  Object  1  NaN  NaN        0
6   NaN  Object  2  NaN  NaN        6
12  NaN  Object  3  NaN  NaN       12
18  NaN  Object  4  NaN  NaN       18
23  NaN  Object  5  NaN  NaN       23
```

```
   desired output:
    0     1       2   3     4     slicing
0   NaN  Object1  NaN  NaN  NaN        0
6   NaN  Object2  NaN  NaN  NaN        6
12  NaN  Object3  NaN  NaN  NaN       12
18  NaN  Object4  NaN  NaN  NaN       18
23  NaN  Object5  NAN  NaN  NaN       23
```

- library pandas
- iterate through each row in the dataset (since there are only NA's and str'Object' with its corresponding str'1-10' number)
- replace str numbers with Na and concatenate data in the same row

Code for now:

df= df[df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('Desk').any().df[row]+df[row], axis=1)]

```
Index      0      1   2    3    4
0         NaN  Desk   1  NaN  NaN
5         NaN  Desk   2  NaN  NaN
10        NaN  Desk   3  NaN  NaN
15        NaN  Desk   4  NaN  NaN
20        NaN  Desk   5  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

Using the following dataframe as an example:

```
       0     1       2   3    4     slicing
index                       
0      NaN   Object  1   NaN  NaN   0
6      NaN   Object  2   NaN  A     6
12     NaN   Object  3   NaN  NaN   12
18     NaN   NaN     4   NaN  NaN   18
23     Stuff Object  NaN 5    NaN   23
```

I perform 4 steps in the below 4 lines of code, when 'Object' exists in column 1: 1) replace nans with nothing; 2) set everything to string type; 3) join the row, to column 1, 4) replace all the other columns with nan

```
df.loc[df['1']=='Object',['0', '2', '3','4']] = df.loc[df['1']=='Object',['0', '2', '3','4']].fillna('')
df.loc[df['1']=='Object',['0','1', '2', '3','4']] = df.loc[df['1']=='Object',['0','1', '2', '3','4']].astype(str)
df.loc[df['1']=='Object', ['1','0', '2', '3','4']] = df.loc[df['1']=='Object', ['1', '0', '2', '3','4']].agg(''.join, axis=1)
df.loc[df['1'].str.contains('Object', na = False), ['0', '2', '3','4']] = np.nan
df

       0    1             2    3     4   slicing
index                       
0      NaN  Object1       NaN  NaN  NaN  0
6      NaN  Object2A      NaN  NaN  NaN  6
12     NaN  Object3       NaN  NaN  NaN  12
18     NaN  NaN           4    NaN  NaN  18
23     NaN  ObjectStuff5  NaN  NaN  NaN  23
```

Comment: Is there a way to iterate through rows instead of specifying the column since the position of the number can vary or will vary depending on the dataframe?

Comment: Basically, I need a similar approach but to be applied only to the rows where 'Desk' is encountered since there is more data in the  second column (2) that doesn't need to be concatenated

Comment: By 'Desk' you mean 'Object' in the original example, correct? Also, when it finds 'Desk', is it then alright to concatenate with column 2?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I meant "object" sorry. No I want to concatenate with anything that is in the same row with 'Object', not through columns

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to achieve, you should really try to wok with columns instead of iterating. It is way faster. You can try something like this :

```
import numpy as np
columns = df.columns.tolist()
ix = df[df[columns[1]].str.contains('Object')].index
df.loc[ix:columns[1]] = df.loc[ix:columns[1]]+df.loc[ix:columns[2]]
df.loc[ix:columns[2]] = np.nan
```